# How to make texture painting easier?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm making game assets and characters in Blender. For easy shapes and simple coloring I use a painting software, then import the texture back into Blender. However, when I'm trying to handpaint models (for example fur patterns on cartoon animal characters etc.) I find it really dificult to do it nicely. I usually end up going back and forth between Blender and a painting software until it looks good enough. Am I simply bad at texture painting? Is there some kind of trick that would make it easier? Or should I try to switch to a 3d texture panting software like Armor Paint or Substance Painter?

Comment: For the moment Blender is much more limited than any painting software, but what difficulty do you meet exactly when painting in Blender? For example do you know all the brushes?

Comment: I know and use all of the brushes that can be found in the tool panel. If there are others, then I don't know about them. Well, the biggest difficulty is that I feel like I can't fully control my lines. Like I find it pretty easy to draw nice lines and shape on a 2D UV map, but mess it up when painting directly onto the 3D model. Ii's not that hard when the topology follows the exact shape I want to color because I can just fill that part, but when I paint over edges and seams I can only use freehand strokes.

Comment: maybe show some screenshots so that we can understand better?

Comment: I think this is too general a question to be possible to answer here - there are many video tutorials and specific posts on getting the most of blender texture paint out there, provided you can concentrate on specific aspects you are looking for. Many approaches exist, and you have to decide for yourself what add-ons you want to employ getting there - and also you need to get familiar with all that is available.

Comment: I mostly wanted to get to know whether I should learn how to texture paint with Blender more thoroughly (through more tutorials, add-ons, etc.) or would it be a waste of time and should I learn to use a texture painting software instead? I'm working on cartoon-ish characters as well as realistic assets, and I'd prefer to master one tool that I can use for all texture painting.